# How to find the list of all the elementary functions in mathematica?

Tags: built-in-symbols

Is there any command to give me the list of all the embedded elementary functions in Mathematica like Cos Sin Cosh Sinh Log and so on?

Comment: I think you need to define what makes a function elementary.

Comment: @kraZug Mathematica has already named it : https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ElementaryFunctions.html

Comment: I think it is safe to say that if there is an elementary function, then Mathematica has it. Now you get to decide what functions are elementary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to use `WolframLanguageData` to get only the functions listed on the referenced page of elementary functions.  The expression

```
WolframLanguageData[
 EntityClass[
  "WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", "BasicFunctions"}]]
```

gives rather more than asked for.  There doesn't seem to be a functionality area closer to what is wanted.

Never mind, we can always read the documentation and do a little string hacking maybe:

```
n1 = Import[$InstallationDirectory ~~ "/Documentation/English/System/Guides/ElementaryFunctions.nb", "Text"];
```

and then after a little data-tasting ...

```
StringCases[n1, 
 "HelpLookup[\"paclet:ref/" ~~ fn : WordCharacter .. ~~ "\"" :> fn]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to enumerate the elementary functions would be through `MathematicalFunctionData[]`:

```
FromEntity /@ MathematicalFunctionData["ElementaryFunctions"]
   {ArcCos, ArcCosh, ArcCot, ArcCoth, ArcCsc, ArcCsch, ArcSec, ArcSech, ArcSin, ArcSinh,
    ArcTan, ArcTanh, ArcTan[#1, #2] &, Cos, Cosh, Cot, Coth, Csc, Csch, Exp, Haversine,
    Log10, Log2, Log[#1, #2] &, Log, #1^#2 &, ProductLog, ProductLog[#1, #2] &, Sec, Sech,
    Sin, Sinc, Sinh, Sqrt, Tan, Tanh}
```

Note the separate entries for the one-argument and two-argument versions of `Log[]`, `ArcTan[]`, and `ProductLog[]`.

One might argue that the Lambert function `ProductLog[]` is not actually elementary, but this is the convention followed by *Mathematica*. Similarly, one might also wonder why e.g. `Gudermannian[]`, `InverseGudermannian[]`, `InverseHaversine[]`, and `LogisticSigmoid[]` aren't in the returned list.