# How to Return All Mathematica Functions in a Domain

Tags: built-in-symbols, entity

We know that `Names["System*"]` and `WolframLanguageData[]` both return the list of all System or "native" functions.

Is there a more advanced command we could use to return a list like this, but for only a relevant subdomain of these functions such as just the mathematical functions (`Sin`, `Cos`, etc.), excluding others such as list operation or visualization functions?

Comment: This - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191142/how-to-find-the-list-of-all-the-elementary-functions-in-mathematica/191149 - by no means provides a complete solution to your question.  But it's not clear how you would define a subdomain of functions, some of the topic pages in the document might be a good place to start.